# Use XML-design of a listview multiple times

Tags: android, xml

I've written an app and now want to design the UI. The problem is that I have the same data (well, not the same, but the same kind of data since it's an XML readout) and now I wanted to design it. But I don't think I can get the design how I want it programmatically. So I thought I design it once with XML and then copy the layout in the for loop for the other data as well. Is this possible?

If yes, how is it possible? I finished now my XML for one entry and now I want that all the other entries have the same style and layout as the others... Thanks!

Comment: Have you read how to use a ListView with custom cell? Point 10 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks. Will report back but I have much data so it's going to take some time. THanks already!

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to achieve this.

There is include tag in xml file which you can use one layout in multiple screen design.

for eg. you had create header for application so no need to use same code in all file, just you can include that portion in each xml file.

here is simple example which may help you.

**Create a Re-usable Layout**

titlebar.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Use the  Tag:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to use another layout in my new layout. I want to design a TextView one time only and then programmatically use it for the next 48, too. The comment below my answer helped me a bit. I will give that a try.

Comment: okey then you can create custom class which is extend by textview or function for create text view  with its style.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an Adapter to define your ListView elements.  In which case, you will define a layout for that adapter (using XML) that will apply to every element in your ListView.

Bottom line, use an Adapter, which will set the same XML layout for every element in your List.

(Check item #3)
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters